# How to wire different backend solutions into a generic API?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, api, architecture

first post, so sorry if I'm breaking any conventions in advance :-)

Wondering how you'd tackle the following scenario.

I have to produce a generic API that provides game tracking functions (track what was clicked, track if a certain event occurred, etc). This generic API needs to wire into one of two (or more) bespoke tracking solutions provided by third parties (e.g. itracku.com and itrackutoo.com) in the background.

The bespoke tracking solutions sport similar functions (trackClick, trackEvent), but vary dramatically in the number of arguments they require (e.g. one requires 1 argument to be passed, the other 6).

In order for the generic API to easily switch between hitting either bespoke solution, am I right in assuming that ALL arguments need to be scoped out beforehand in order to facilitate switching tracking solutions? The desire is to NOT have to recomplie .swfs in order to switch tracking solution (i.e. it's switched via an XML config). I was thinking of achieving this by having my generic API functions accept a single object as an argument, e.g.

```
// itracku.com
iTrackUObj:Object = new Object();
iTrackuObj.param1 = 1;

// itrackutoo.com
iTrackUTooObj:Object = new Object();
iTrackUTooObj.param1 = 1;
iTrackUTooObj.param1 = 2;
iTrackUTooObj.param1 = 3;
iTrackUTooObj.param1 = 4;
iTrackUTooObj.param1 = 5;
iTrackUTooObj.param1 = 6;

// my generic function, which accepts an object as a single parameter then validates the object
myGenericFunction(iTrackUObj);

//…or

myGenericFunction(iTrackUTooObj);
```

Can you think of a more efficient way to achieve this? It's more of a technical architech question than an ActionScript one I think, but I think the above might be a bit clunky in real-world use.

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Comment: It'd be easier to give an answer if we knew what the parameters are for. I realize it probably differs from function to function, but an actual example would make it easier to give an answer.

Comment: Tracking clicks and events within the Flash application basically. So "myGenericFunction" could be "trackClick" and the arguments required for one backend solution would only be an ID but for the other potentially a list of data including URL, referrer, screen resolution, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it personally is create a generic TrackObj with every possible parameter any of the tracking backends could possibly use. Then that TrackObj is passed to your generic TrackFunction and inside the function it creates either a TrackU or TrackUToo object and passes it to the XML config chosen backend.

This way your API has its own generic frontend API where as long as you meet the requirements of your API, the user is automatically meeting the requirements of any API they could possibly be using in the backing. This will mean that users will always have to provide 6 parameters, even though their backend only requires one. This can be made easier on the user though with intelligent default values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like trying to take into account all possible arguments before compiling the .swf is the only way I can go. Sensible default values would make things easier alright but a lot of the arguments will be compulsory rather than optional. Hmm...